# Determinant with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

**Question**

In $\Bbb R _{n-2}[X]$, let $f_1(x),\dots, f_n(x) \in \Bbb R _{n-2}[X]$ and let $a_1,\dots, a_n \in \Bbb R$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} f_1(a_1) &f_1(a_2) & \dots & f_1(a_n) \\ \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\f_n(a_1) &f_n(a_2) & \dots & f_n(a_n)\end{bmatrix}$$

What is $\det(A)$?

**Thought**
We claim it's $0$ because $n$ vectors in an $n-1$ dimensional vector space are linearly dependent. And therefore the matrix is singular. Is this a true direction? (Never seen such a question before).

Comment: What is ${\bf R}_{n-2}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Apparently, $\mathbb R_{d}[X]$ is the space of polynomials in $X$ of degree $\le d$ with coefficients in $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

You have a linear dependence among the $f_i$ as elements in $\mathbb R_{n-2}[X]$, that is real numbers $c_i$ not all zero such that $\sum c_if_i$ is the zero polynomial. Then also $\sum c_if_i(a_j)=0$ for all $j$, i.e. the row vectors are linearly dependent as elements of $\mathbb R^n$, hence $\det A=0$.